# Bertrand's postulate strong form

Tags: number-theory

It is easy to find a proof of the weak form of Bertrand's postulate, namely for $n>1$ there is  a prime number $p$ lying strictly between $n$ and $2n$. The strong form states that for $n>3$ there is a prime $p$ lying strictly between $n$ and $2(n-1)$. Where can one find a proof of this? This question raises another: Is there a $k$ such that for $n>k$ there is a prime $p$ lying strictly between $n$ and $2(n-2)$? Of course we may extend this question further by replacing $n-2$ by $n-3$ and so on

Comment: My suspicion is that a sufficiently close look at a proof of what you call weak Bertrand would reveal a simple modification for getting what you call strong Bertrand. Anyway, much stronger results are known, e.g., for $n\ge25$, there is a prime between $n$ and $6n/5$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In fact, I am doing what you suggest, namely looking at standard proofs and trying to modify them. You say that stronger results are known. Do you have a reference?

Comment: There's an article on Bertrand's Postulate at Wikipedia, with a section on stronger results. Also, one proof of Bertrand goes by letting ${2n\choose n}=AB$ where $A$ has only primes $p\le n$ and $B$ has only primes $n\lt p\lt2n$, then showing $n\ge128$ implies $${2n\choose n}\gt4^n/(2n)\gt(2n)^{\sqrt{2n}/2}4^{2n/3}\gt A$$ So $B$ exceeds the quotient of the two quantities in the middle, which, for large $n$, shows it can't be a single prime.

Comment: @GerryMyerson say we had to prove for $p \leq 2n-3$, in this inequality, would you just change the $2n$ to $2n-3$?

Comment: @man, follow a proof through to see what changes you have to make.